# Calling destructor inside constructor

Tags: c++

Hello I have this class:

```
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class DateTimes
        {
        private:
            int month;
            int day;
            float startTime;
            float endTime;
            bool checkValid()
            {
                if(month<1 or month>12)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if(day<1 or day>7)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if(startTime-floor(startTime)>59)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if(endTime-floor(endTime)>59)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        public:
            DateTimes()
            {
            }
            DateTimes(int monthy,int dayy,float startTimey,float endTimey)
            {
              month = monthy;
              day = dayy;
              startTime = startTimey;
              endTime  = endTimey;
              if(!checkValid())
              {              
              }
            }
            ~DateTimes()
            {
            }
};//
```

I want to destroy the Object if `checkValid()` is false.

I tried out calling the destructor `this.~DateTimes()` but the editor doesnt let me to do that.What should I try instead?For the time being I dont print out a message inside the destructor to let me know that the object has been destroyed.

I am using the 2023 version of C++

Comment: Don't. Just throw an exception.

Comment: I dont want to throw a exception.

Comment: Neither do you want to call the destructor.

Comment: If you don't thrown an exception how does the caller of the constructor know the object creation has failed?  Throw an exception.

Comment: @RichardCritten by calling the destructor?I want the object to be removed off for memory management for this project I may use up hundreds of DateTimes

Comment: *I tried out calling the destructor this.~DateTimes()* -- C++ is not a recipe book.  You can't add your own "ingredients".

Comment: _"...by calling the destructor..."_ Which does not pass any information to the caller.  Any attempted used of  an object which is not completely constructed is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way. If it was not you who have created an object, it should not be you who destroys it.

Comment: _"...up hundreds of DateTimes..."_ then use 2-phase construction.

Comment: @Evg but you can manually call the constructor in the main?It is a inherited property of all classes.

Comment: @RootGroves Your method of calling the destructor will not work `{ DateTime d(100, 100, 100.0, 100.0); }` -- Let's say you called the destructor yourself.  Then what happens when the closing `}` is reached?  The destructor of `d` will be called *again*, and who knows what damage will be done, since the object was destroyed.

Comment: @RichardCritten what is a 2-phase construction?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie s*** you are correct.

Comment: In simple words, any constructor call is automatically paired with a destructor call. If you call a destructor manually, it will be called __twice__ and this makes no sense. First red flag. Also note that object construction consists of two phases: memory allocation and object initialization in that memory space. Calling `~DateTimes()` will execute a destructor but it won't deallocate memory. This should be a second red flag.

Comment: A constructor that finishes creates an object. Once a constructor is invoked, the only way to avoid object creation is to make the constructor not finish. The only way to make a constructor not finish is to throw an exception from it. There is no way around this. So if you don't want to throw an exception, your unwanted object will be created. Now it's your job to invent a way to flag objects as unwanted, and to process this flag as appropriate in the rest of your program.

Comment: @RootGroves "*what is a 2-phase construction?*" - it's when you move your initialization logic to a separate method of the class, and then call that method after the constructor exits. The method can return error info to the caller if you don't want to throw an exception, so the caller can decide whether or not to use the constructed object.

Comment: ...but just to be clear: 2-phase construction means all the rest of the code has to deal with the possibility of an unusable object. Throwing an exception is nearly always preferable. The other possibility would be to make `check_valid` a public static member function, and only try to create an object after you've verified that the data is valid (or have a public, static member function that can, with a signature like: `Date *parseDate(std::string const &input);` to parse and return a pointer to a date object, or a null pointer when the input isn't a valid date). But the pointer is clumsy too.

Comment: Alternative: Going one step further you get `DateTimesFactory` which returns `std::optional`. It validates the input and then either constructs or doesn't construct. The constructor is usually the worst place to determine whether you want the object or not. Either test first or take your chances with two-phase construction.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly calling a destructor is almost always wrong. It should only be done if you created an object manually with a non-allocating placement-new.

A constructor can only fail by throwing an exception. It can't leave an object in an non-constructed state. There would be no way for the caller of the constructor to recognize that state. This is the major reason to have exceptions in the language in the first place.

If you don't want or can't use exceptions, then you must assure that the constructor can't fail. So the `checkValid` must be done *before* initializing the object.

For example you can make the constructor `private`, remove the validity check from it,  and then have a member function

```
static std::optional<DateTimes> make(int monthy,int dayy,float startTimey,float endTimey) {
    if(checkValid(monthy, dayy, startTimey, endTimey)) {
        return DateTimes(monthy, dayy, startTimey, endTimey);
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

Instead of constructing an object directly, the user would then call this static `make` member function and gets a `std::optional` which they can check against being empty to detect whether or not construction was successfull.

---

By the way, you shouldn't declare the destructor at all. That's a violation of the rule-of-zero/three/five, which is a rule that should always be followed and always preferring zero over three/five.

The default constructor should also not exist. It doesn't initialize any member, leaving the object in a completely uninitialized state, which a constructor should never do.

---

Also, based on comments, note that it *isn't* the destructor's job to deallocate the memory that the object occupies. That's not a responsibility of the class itself at all. The memory is provided by the user of the class and the class itself only places the object into that memory, starting its lifetime and initializing its state. The destructor's job is only to release resources used by the object and ending the lifetime of the object. It doesn't release its storage.

On the other hand throwing an exception from the constructor assures that the storage which the object would occupy is correctly released either automatically by the compiler (if the object has automatic storage duration) or by whoever allocated the storage for the object (assuming the code using the class is written correctly in an exception-safe manner, which C++ code should be in general).

Comment: Hi.How can throwing a Exception fail the constructor?Can you give out a example of it?

Comment: @RootGroves Do you know how throwing exceptions works in general? Just do the same in the constructor. If you don't, there should be a chapter on exceptions in every introduction to C++. Something like `throw std::invalid_argument("Some error message here.");`.

Comment: @RootGroves  The standard specifies what happens when a constructor throws.  Essentially, all members and bases already constructed (in the initialiser list, or implicitly) are destroyed (destructors called) in reverse order of their construction.   Anything done in the constructor body itself (e.g. a `new` expression) must be undone in the constructor body before throwing the exception, since they will not be automatically undone.